# Vue Vuetify center horizontally and vertically

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to center my auth component (v-card) horizontally and vertically. I tried all kinds of solutions like `justify=center` and `align=center` on the rows, fill-height on the v-container, `class="fill-height"` on the v-container but its not working. What am I doing wrong here ?

**Code :**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useUserStore } from "../../stores/user";
const store = useUserStore();
</script>
<template>
        <v-card width="800" >
          <v-card-title>
            Authentication
          </v-card-title>
          <v-card-subtitle>
            login with username and password
          </v-card-subtitle>
          <v-card-text>
            <v-row>
              <v-col cols="12" md="6">
                <v-text-field v-model="store.username" label="Username"></v-text-field>
              </v-col>
              <v-col cols="12" md="6">
                <v-text-field v-model="store.password" label="Password"></v-text-field>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import Auth from "../components/auth/Auth.component.vue"

</script>
<template>
    <v-container>
    <v-row style="border:1px solid red;" fill-height>
      <v-col class="d-flex justify-center items-center">
        <Auth/>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    </v-container>
</template>

<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">

</script>
```

Comment: give the `align-center justify-center` classes on `v-row` insted of `v-col`. remove all classes from `v-col`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

Check this codesanbox I made: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack71483246-center-login-p1u6zv?file=/src/views/Home.vue

Looks like by just adding the class `fill-height` to the root container you can center it vertically.

```html
<template>
   <v-container fluid class="fill-height">
      <v-row style="border:1px solid red;">
         <v-col class="d-flex justify-center">
            <Auth/>
         </v-col>
      </v-row>
   </v-container>
</template>
```

[image: Preview]

Comment: thank you, actually I figured out that vuetify 3 alpha with vite seems to be the issue. Your example works for me with vuetify 2 but not 3 alpha.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet will center the card vertically in the parent in Vuetify 3:

```
<v-row align="center" class="fill-height">
  <v-col>
    <v-card class="ma-3">
      Sample Content
    </v-card>
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```